# How to detect if offset points that are on a zoomable plane is within a circle

Tags: flutter, dart

We have a Stack() with an InteractiveViewer() widget, and a CustomPaint widget that draws a circle on the screen. The InteractiveViewer() contains a Stack(), with children that consists of an image, and a list of Offset(x,y) points.

Our goal is to determine how many of the points falls within the Circle. This works fine when on zoom level one, but when we zoom / pan the calculations are off.

We need help with the translations.

Steps:

1. Choose any image
2. Play with the slider
3. See correct count at the top
4. Zoom in on the image
5. See incorrect count

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

class Tester extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesterState createState() => _TesterState();
}

class _TesterState extends State<Tester> {
  double _radius = 100;
  final _random = new Random();
  double _imageWidth = 0;
  double _imageHeight = 0;
  File? _imageFile;
  int _count = 0;
  List<DotBox> _boxes = [];
  List<DotBox> _tBoxes = [];
  TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();

  // Used for generating points for the tester
  int next(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);

  // Generic formula to determine if points are inside other points
  static bool isPointInside(Offset point, Offset center, double radius) {
    return math.pow((point.dx + 12.5) - center.dx, 2) + math.pow((point.dy + 12.5) - center.dy, 2) < math.pow(radius, 2);
  }

  // Simple image picker to choose an image. The project code uses the a image with dots on, for testing purpose any image can be used
  chooseImageToProcess() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final File? imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      if (imageFile == null) return;

      // Get the selected image with and height that will be used later
      FileImage(imageFile).resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) {
            setState(() {
              _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
              _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
            });
          },
        ),
      );
      setState(() => _imageFile = imageFile);
    }
  }

  // Iterate through the generated points, and check if the point falls within the main circle
  countPointsInside(Size logicalSize, double radius) {
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      // This is what is used to determine the correct scale - Not sure if its correct???
      double factorX = (logicalSize.width) * _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
      double factorY = (_imageHeight / _imageWidth * logicalSize.width) * _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
      Offset centerPoint = Offset((factorX / 2) - 12.5, (factorY / 2) - 12.5);
      Offset tCenterPoint = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(_transformationController.value, centerPoint);

      _count = 0;

      _tBoxes = [];

      _tBoxes.add(
        DotBox(
          point: centerPoint,
          imageWidth: _imageWidth,
          imageHeight: _imageHeight,
          pointSize: Size.square(25),
          color: Colors.pink,
          label: 'C',
        ),
      );

      _tBoxes.add(
        DotBox(
          point: tCenterPoint,
          imageWidth: _imageWidth,
          imageHeight: _imageHeight,
          pointSize: Size.square(25),
          color: Colors.green,
          label: 'C',
        ),
      );

      int index = 0;
      _boxes.forEach((DotBox box) {
        Offset point = Offset(box.point.dx, box.point.dy);
        Offset tPoint = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(_transformationController.value, point);

        _tBoxes.add(
          DotBox(
            point: tPoint,
            imageWidth: _imageWidth,
            imageHeight: _imageHeight,
            pointSize: Size.square(25),
            color: Colors.blue,
            label: '$index',
          ),
        );

        index++;

        if (isPointInside(tPoint, tCenterPoint, radius)) {
          _count++;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Generate test points for testing
  List<Widget> _generateTestPoints() {
    if (_imageFile != null && _imageWidth != 0 && _imageHeight != 0 && _boxes.isEmpty) {
      final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      _boxes = List.generate(5, (index) {
        return DotBox(
          point: Offset((logicalSize.width / 2) - 12.5, next(20, 300).toDouble()),
          imageWidth: _imageWidth,
          imageHeight: _imageHeight,
          pointSize: Size.square(25),
          label: '$index',
        );
      });
    }

    return _boxes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    _boxes.clear();
                    _tBoxes.clear();
                  }),
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh)),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // The interactive viewer is used to allow the user to zoom in and out the image. We need the user to be able to zoom to certain parts of the image to check how many dots are in the circle
            Center(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    _imageFile != null ? Image.file(_imageFile!) : ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => chooseImageToProcess(), child: Text('Choose image')),
                  ]
                    ..addAll(_generateTestPoints())
                    ..addAll(_tBoxes),
                ),
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                maxScale: 5,
                transformationController: _transformationController,
              ),
            ),
            //This is whats used as a reference in the screen, we need to count the dots that falls within this screen
            CustomPaint(
              foregroundPainter: CircleShapePainter(_radius),
              child: Container(height: double.infinity),
            ),
            // The slider is used to increase / decrease the circle radius.
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Slider(
                value: _radius,
                min: 10,
                max: 300,
                divisions: 10,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _radius = value;
                    countPointsInside(logicalSize, _radius);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Text('Count $_count')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A simple circle painter
class CircleShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  double radius;

  CircleShapePainter(this.radius);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

// The box that will be drawn on the image. These are the dots that need to be counted
class DotBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final double imageHeight;
  final double imageWidth;
  final Offset point;
  final Size pointSize;
  final Color color;
  final String label;

  DotBox({required this.imageHeight, required this.imageWidth, required this.point, required this.pointSize, this.color = Colors.red, required this.label});

  _box() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.circle, color: this.color),
        Center(child: Text(label)),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double factorX = logicalSize.width;
    double factorY = (imageHeight / imageWidth * logicalSize.width);

    return Positioned(
      left: point.dx,
      top: point.dy,
      width: pointSize.width,
      height: pointSize.height,
      child: _box(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:
The counts are correct, but its counting wrong because the coords are wrong.

I Added screens with the results of the translate.

1. The first one shows the dots at zoom level 1 (The red is the original points, the blue is the translated points.)
2. The second one shows the dots at zoom 1.5.(The red is the original points, the blue is the translated points)

I think the translate isn't working correctly because the circle / reference center isn't in the same plane / inside the InteractiveViewer. This is by design, i don't want the circle to resize with the InteractiveViewer. The circle is drawn on top op the InteractiveViewer with a Stack, and the radius controlled by the slider.

Comment: check `TransformationController` class

Comment: Thank you @pskink, i saw but i dont know how to use it in this case

Comment: `transformedOffset = MatrixUtils.transformPoint(controller.value, someOffset)`

Comment: I edited the origina question to include the transformpoint. I added it to both the points being checked, and the circle center

Comment: just print `tPoint` and see if it is mapped to correct value

Comment: Its not mapping to the correct values, i updated the question with the code used to produce the screenshots thats also attached.

Comment: i check that and it seems that matrix in the controller is ok

Comment: I guess the problem then is translating the centre of the circle ( in this case the centre of the screen ) to the interactiveViewer in the plane below. IE plotting an offset on the interactiveViewer based on the centre point of the screen taking zoom and pan into consideration

Comment: or you can do the opposite, call `transformedCenter = controller.toScene(centerPoint)` - it maps from screen coords to viewer coords - then you can simply do `(sceneOffset - transformedCenter).distance` where `sceneOffset` is `Offset(box.point.dx, box.point.dy);`

Comment: Thank you @pskink! toScene was the way to go!

Comment: the first way would work too: you have N points on the "scene" and one point on the "screen" - so either map that one point to "scene" or map N points to "screen" - however mapping one point to "scene" seems to be faster

Comment: and you don't have to use those `math.pow` called several times as `Offset` has `distance` property

Answer (score 1):

This is what i ended up with!

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

class Tester extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesterState createState() => _TesterState();
}

class _TesterState extends State<Tester> {
  double _radius = 100;
  final _random = new Random();
  double _imageWidth = 0;
  double _imageHeight = 0;
  File? _imageFile;
  int _count = 0;
  List<DotBox> _boxes = [];
  List<DotBox> _tBoxes = [];
  TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();

  // Used for generating points for the tester
  int next(int min, int max) => min + _random.nextInt(max - min);

  // Generic formula to determine if points are inside other points
  static bool isPointInside(Offset point, Offset center, double radius) {
    return math.pow((point.dx + 12.5) - center.dx, 2) + math.pow((point.dy + 12.5) - center.dy, 2) < math.pow(radius, 2);
  }

  // Simple image picker to choose an image. The project code uses the a image with dots on, for testing purpose any image can be used
  chooseImageToProcess() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final File? imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      if (imageFile == null) return;

      // Get the selected image with and height that will be used later
      FileImage(imageFile).resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) {
            setState(() {
              _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
              _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
            });
          },
        ),
      );
      setState(() => _imageFile = imageFile);
    }
  }

  // Iterate through the generated points, and check if the point falls within the main circle
  countPointsInside(Size logicalSize, double radius) {
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      // This is what is used to determine the correct scale - Not sure if its correct???
      double factorX = logicalSize.width;
      double factorY = (_imageHeight / _imageWidth * logicalSize.width);
      Offset centerPoint = Offset((factorX / 2), (factorY / 2));

      MatrixDecomposedValues matrixValues = MatrixGestureDetector.decomposeToValues(_transformationController.value);

      _count = 0;
      _tBoxes = [];

      Offset tCenterPoint = _transformationController.toScene(centerPoint);
      _boxes.forEach((DotBox box) {
        Offset point = Offset(box.point.dx, box.point.dy);
        if (isPointInside(point, tCenterPoint, radius / matrixValues.scale)) {
          _count++;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  // Generate test points for testing
  List<Widget> _generateTestPoints() {
    if (_imageFile != null && _imageWidth != 0 && _imageHeight != 0 && _boxes.isEmpty) {
      final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      _boxes = List.generate(5, (index) {
        return DotBox(
          point: Offset((logicalSize.width / 2) - 12.5, 50 * index.toDouble()),
          imageWidth: _imageWidth,
          imageHeight: _imageHeight,
          pointSize: Size.square(25),
          label: '$index',
        );
      });
    }

    return _boxes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
              _boxes.clear();
              _tBoxes.clear();
            }),
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() => countPointsInside(logicalSize, _radius)),
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // The interactive viewer is used to allow the user to zoom in and out the image. We need the user to be able to zoom to certain parts of the image to check how many dots are in the circle
            Center(
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    _imageFile != null ? Image.file(_imageFile!) : ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => chooseImageToProcess(), child: Text('Choose image')),
                  ]
                    ..addAll(_generateTestPoints())
                    ..addAll(_tBoxes),
                ),
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                maxScale: 5,
                transformationController: _transformationController,
                onInteractionUpdate: (_) {
                  setState(() {
                    countPointsInside(logicalSize, _radius);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            //This is whats used as a reference in the screen, we need to count the dots that falls within this screen
            CustomPaint(
              foregroundPainter: CircleShapePainter(_radius),
              child: Container(height: double.infinity),
            ),
            // The slider is used to increase / decrease the circle radius.
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Slider(
                value: _radius,
                min: 10,
                max: 300,
                //divisions: 10,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _radius = value;
                    countPointsInside(logicalSize, _radius);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Card(child: Text('Count $_count'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A simple circle painter
class CircleShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  double radius;

  CircleShapePainter(this.radius);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

// The box that will be drawn on the image. These are the dots that need to be counted
class DotBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final double imageHeight;
  final double imageWidth;
  final Offset point;
  final Size pointSize;
  final Color color;
  final String label;

  DotBox({required this.imageHeight, required this.imageWidth, required this.point, required this.pointSize, this.color = Colors.red, required this.label});

  _box() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.circle, color: this.color),
          Center(child: Text(label)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double factorX = logicalSize.width;
    double factorY = (imageHeight / imageWidth * logicalSize.width);

    return Positioned(
      left: point.dx,
      top: point.dy,
      width: pointSize.width,
      height: pointSize.height,
      child: _box(),
    );
  }
}
```